# Cloud Spanner Rename Column

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ddl, google-cloud-spanner

I am attempting to rename a table column in cloud spanner.  Is there a way to do this without creating a new column, coping the old values and then dropping the old column?  Reading through the [cloud spanner documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table) it is unclear if this operation is possible.  The only way I can get this to work is with the DDL statement and intermediate DML SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN col_name STRING(1024);
-- Between these steps make a DML statement to copy the data over before dropping the old table
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN new_col_name;
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN new_col_name STRING(1024) NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some limitations on schema changes:

- No support for renaming tables and columns
- A column’s type can’t be changed
- A table’s primary key can’t be altered

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, John.  I ended up implementing what I originally laid out as a potential solution.  I'm marking your response as correct.